# Search text from textbox using dialog in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have reachtextbox and want to search text like notepad in silverlight in separate dialog.. Find text and search that text in huge text entered in richtextbox. 
How can I do it using separate dialog like notepad and search text and edit and highlight it in richtextbox?

Comment: No not MVVM. its normal service based page.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a Mediator to send messages between search form and text form. You can declare an event like "OnSearch" in your search form and suscribe to it from your text form. When the event raises, you should send an eventarg with the string you want to search.

The text form should suscribe to the "searchMessage" with a string parameter. The Business layer for text form should implement a "search" method that looks for every string/substring depending on your search options. Then change text color for each coincidence.

Searching strings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228630(v=vs.80).aspx

You can also use the Find method in RichTextBox.

To change the color of that text you have to set the text as selected and then change the color of that selection:
SelectionStart, SelectionLenght, SelectionColor.

Comment: Yes but I want to give separate dialog which will search desired text entered in my richtextbox and select that much part searched. I can do it using child window but problem in child window I am facing is cannot go back to parent window where my richtext box exists..

Comment: That's what I mean to do with the Mediator. The new form should send a Message like "searchString("test")". You can see how this works with, for example, MVVM Light messenger (you can use a messenger anyway). If you don't want to use a messenger, you should use events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx

Comment: ok.. let me give it a try to make new form/dialog separate from my page so I can search from it.